# openGL - understanding colors changes due to lightning

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am writing some software in C, to render a yellow and a brown cube. However once I programmed light, all the colors changes to light blue. Could someone explain me why the colors changed? And how I can prevent such an extreme change?

This is the code I used for the light:

```
GLfloat color1 = {0.633, 0.237, 0.170}; \\ changed to blue

void initLight()
{

    GLfloat red[] = {1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
    GLfloat white[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
    GLfloat blueGreen[]     = {0.0,0.4,1.0,1.0};

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, white); 
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,white); 
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,blueGreen);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,127.0); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you're using immediate mode, I assume you wrote something that looks like this setting up the vertices?

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(/*...*/);
glColor3f(/*...*/);
/*...*/
glEnd();
```

When you add lighting to the scene, the renderer no longer considers the color values you proposed for the individual vertices, and instead substitutes in white or grey (causing the light to turn those faces blueish-green). To fix that, you need to tell the renderer to treat the vertex colors as material colors. This code should be sufficient:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

This is, of course, also a reason why you really, *really* should not be using OpenGL's immediate mode or Fixed Function Pipeline rendering, as it causes problems like this. I recommend the tutorial found [here](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Introduction) for learning Modern OpenGL.

Edit: Fixed a Typo

## DOUBLE EDIT COMBO:

Alright, so there's a few other things you'll need to take into account.

```
GLfloat lp0[] = {4.0,4.0,3.0,0.0};
```

Generally speaking, position vectors should have their `w` component (the last one) set to 1, not 0. You may want to change it to

```
GLfloat lp0[] = {4.0,4.0,3.0,1.0};
```

Beyond that, you'll want to try playing around with the position, particularly using things like matrix adjustments. Again; this is yet another reason not to use FFP, and in this case, it's because it's difficult to tell where the light is being positioned relative to the objects. Putting it at `<4,4,3>` in worldspace only makes sense if you know for certain that its position is being translated by the modelview and projection matrices correctly, and at least in the code that I'm seeing, that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Yes I use glVertex() and glColor.

I am using very oldstyle openGL.  error: ‘GL_MATERIAL_COLOR’ undeclared.

Any workaround?

Comment: @J.Doe There was a typo in my code snippet. It's supposed to be `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`, not `GL_MATERIAL_COLOR`.

Comment: indeed that solved the issue. However I don't see the effect of the light anymore. I am back to my starting point, it looks like I didnt use any light...

Comment: @J.Doe Based on the code you provided, I don't see any code which sets the location or direction of the light.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

You probably should also call:

```
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
```

Also, your ambient light is very bright. You may need to bring the intensity of your ambient light down somewhat to get the proper effect from the tinted diffuse light.